# Typescript add once for each date in array (multiple dates)

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an array of Objects which have a few fields. It looks like this:

```
[
    {"date": "01/01/2020", "location": "Main St", "customers": 100, "shoppers": 150, "visitors": 2000},
    {"date": "01/01/2020", "location": "Lower St", "customers": 105, "shoppers": 166, "visitors": 2000},
    {"date": "01/01/2020", "location": "High St", "customers": 180, "shoppers": 260, "visitors": 2000},
    {"date": "02/01/2020", "location": "Main St", "customers": 156, "shoppers": 194, "visitors": 1566},
    {"date": "02/01/2020", "location": "Lower St", "customers": 80, "shoppers": 201, "visitors": 1566},
    {"date": "02/01/2020", "location": "High St", "customers": 97, "shoppers": 133, "visitors": 1566},
    {"date": "03/01/2020", "location": "Main St", "customers": 48, "shoppers": 97, "visitors": 1002},
    {"date": "03/01/2020", "location": "Lower St", "customers": 211, "shoppers": 287, "visitors": 1002},
    {"date": "03/01/2020", "location": "High St", "customers": 113, "shoppers": 233, "visitors": 1002}
]
```

As you can see, the visitor number is constant each day (as it is already total visitors for that day).

I am summing the customers and shoppers as follows:

```
this.customerCount = this.data.filter(item => item.date >= this.startDate && item.date <= this.endDate)
      .reduce((sum, current) => sum + current.customers, 0);

this.shopperCount = this.data.filter(item => item.date >= this.startDate && item.date <= this.endDate)
      .reduce((sum, current) => sum + current.shoppers, 0);
```

This is working as expected and shopperCount is equal to the sum of all shopperCount values between two chosen dates.

Can anyone advise how I sum all visitor values between two dates but only taking each visitor value once per day? So in the dataset above, the visitorCount would equal:

```
2000 + 1566 + 1002 = 4568
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you should do is to fix the data comparison, this date comparison would not work in all cases in my opinion, either convert the date format to `yyyy-mm-dd` or date objects and then do date comparisons.

Once you have fixed that, you may use Array.reduce to get the visitors sum this way:

```
const sum = this.data.reduce((acc, item) => 
    {
        if (item.date >= this.startDate && item.date <= this.endDate) {
            if (!acc.map[item.date.toString()]) {
                acc.map[item.date.toString()] = true;
                acc.sum += item.visitors;
            }
        }
        return acc;
    }, {map: {}, sum: 0}).sum;
```

Comment: What does the item.data refer to?

Comment: @nimgwfc That was a typo, "data" insterad of "date", had edited long back.

Comment: That is what I thought, thanks! Although i get an error that item.date cannot be used as an index type as it is of type Date

Comment: @nimgwfc Its a typescript warning and it looks as if your dates are anyway strings but anyhow, the above edit should make the warning go away.